# Handmade auto template (without using C++0x)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can be realized the **auto** keyword functionality without using c++0x standard?

```
for(std::deque<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it = points.begin();
    it != points.end(); ++it)
{
   ...
}
```

Maybe such class:

```
class AUTO
{
public:
   template <typename T1>
   AUTO(T1);

   template <typename T2>
   operator T2();
};
```

With such usage:

```
for(AUTO it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
{
   ...
}
```

But, T1 and T2 are different.
How to move info about T1  to *operator T2()*?
Is it really possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a library extension was easily implementable there would have been no need for a language extension. See [N1607](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1607.pdf) for details on the auto proposal.

However, the [article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html) on the [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html) (which sort of does what you want) macro may help understand the issues related to such an implementation.

> **What is BOOST_FOREACH?**
>
> In C++, writing a loop that iterates
>   over a sequence is tedious. We can
>   either use iterators, which requires a
>   considerable amount of boiler-plate,
>   or we can use the std::for_each()
>   algorithm and move our loop body into
>   a predicate, which requires no less
>   boiler-plate and forces us to move our
>   logic far from where it will be used.
>   In contrast, some other languages,
>   like Perl, provide a dedicated
>   "foreach" construct that automates
>   this process. BOOST_FOREACH is just
>   such a construct for C++. It iterates
>   over sequences for us, freeing us from
>   having to deal directly with iterators
>   or write predicates.
>
> BOOST_FOREACH is designed for
>   ease-of-use and efficiency. It does no
>   dynamic allocations, makes no virtual
>   function calls or calls through
>   function pointers, and makes no calls
>   that are not transparent to the
>   compiler's optimizer. This results in
>   near-optimal code generation; the
>   performance of BOOST_FOREACH is
>   usually within a few percent of the
>   equivalent hand-coded loop. And
>   although BOOST_FOREACH is a macro, it
>   is a remarkably well-behaved one. It
>   evaluates its arguments exactly once,
>   leading to no nasty surprises.

Comment: I think about implementation only for using in for like foreach. The C++0x's keyword auto have a lot of usages... Thanks for link, i'll read.

Comment: @k06a: There's a strong opposition in C++ to implement something as a new language feature when it can be implemented in a library. So if something ends up in the language proper you can be pretty sure that nobody has found a way to properly do it in a library. (For example, what `std::function` and `std::bind` do is built into the language in many other languages, but it's a library feature in C++.)

Comment: I've always wondered why BOOST_FOREACH is a few percent away from a "hand-coded" loop.

Comment: @sbi: and one can't help but note that both `std::function` and what `std::bind` produce is a rather suboptimal representation of a closure. They actually tried to introduce a better one alongside C++0x lambdas - early proposals required that a `[&]` lambda be an instance of a specific, well-known "magical" function type, which the compiler could then efficiently implement as pointer to code + pointer to stack frame (which cannot be done portably by the programmer). Sadly, that part of it got killed.

Answer (score 10):

There's a [BOOST_AUTO](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html) macro that more or less does what the auto keyword... However, one look at it's implementation will tell you that it's far better to find a way to use C++0x :>

Comment: Also, if the compiler doesn't support decltype or typeof, BOOST_AUTO will only be able to handle the built-in types as well as many standard library types. Other user.defined types have to be "registered" so that BOOST_AUTO recognizes them -- if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these macros to work-around this in a Standard conforming manner.

```
#define DEF_DED(D, E) any_base const & D = make_any_concrete((E))
#define DED(D, E) get_t(D, true ? ded_ty() : get_idt((E)))

template<typename T> struct id {
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
id<T> get_idt(T t) { return id<T>(); }

struct any_base { };

template<typename D>
struct any_concrete : any_base {
  any_concrete(D d):d(d) {}
  mutable D d;
};

template<typename T>
any_concrete<T> make_any_concrete(T x) { return any_concrete<T>(x); }

struct ded_ty {
  template<typename T>
  operator id<T>() { return id<T>(); }
};

template<typename T>
T &get_t(any_base const &b, id<T>) { return static_cast<any_concrete<T> const&>(b).d; }
```

So your for-loop becomes

```
for(DEF_DED(it, points.begin()); 
    DED(it, points.begin()) != points.end(); 
  ++DED(it, points.begin()))
{
   ...
}
```

Credit goes to [Conditional Love: FOREACH Redux](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html), by Eric Niebler. Not sure whether this is really worth it though :)

Answer (score 2):

The more immediate problem is to get information from the deduced type to a data member declaration.

```
class AUTO
{
public:
   template <typename T1>
   AUTO(T1);

   T1 state; // eg deque<...>::iterator - need this!
};
```

That's clearly not going to happen because the `AUTO` object must be allocated before the function is called.

Given `typeof` or `decltype`, it's not so hard, though.

```
#define AUTO( name, initializer ) typeof( initializer ) name = initializer
```

Of course, this has a lot of restrictions. And `typeof` isn't standard. With multiple compiler support, this would probably be the basis for those Boost tools.